# How to publish data in a room from a .NET code?

Tags: node.js, httprequest, socket.io

I have a webservice written in .NET ... I need to send a command from this webservice to the socket.io server that will make the server publish the data on a channel. I have done this with APE by sending a HTTP request. But, i am unable to figure out how to do it in socket.io

Has anyone done anything like this before in socket.io?

Thanks

Comment: "the server" "the data" -- ah yes, I know the one you're talking about.

Comment: Oh, come onnnn. Anyways, server stands for socket.io and data refers to the data that i want to publish on the room.

Comment: What's a "room" in this context?

Comment: a room is like a chat room. In the jargon of comet, u can refer to a room as "channels"

Answer (score 0):

I have an older example where I accomplished this by listening on different ports:

```
var http = require('http'),
io = require('socket.io');


/** standard http requests **
******************************/
server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
// your server code 
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
res.end('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});
server.listen(80);


/*** server to server connections ***
 ***********************************/
var serverConnections = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // ... parse params and broadcast message to the socket.io 
    //  connections attached below...
    // ... 
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('done');
});
serverConnections.listen(8080);

/*** socket.io connections **/
*****************************/
var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function (client) { ... });
```

Comment: I am sorry. This is not what i am looking for. I want the data to be published from .NET. On a 2nd note, you dont have to create 2 servers on 2 ports to simulate the chat room. In socket.io 0.7, u have the concept of rooms. Check out the google groups of socket.io